# Regedit as Current User

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-registry

I'm trying to apply a registry fix for an Outlook/O365 issue on a user's account. The issue is that "regedit" is blocked by a domain GPO. I'm able to run "gpedit" using the local admin account.

Question : When I run "regedit as the local admin, am I modifying the registry for the local admin user or the domain user who's actually logged onto the workstation?

I'm trying to apply the following fix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2843677

Also, the path for the above mentioned registry should end in " \Preferences" which is what I'm unable to locate. I'm able to navigate up until \Outlook.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Running Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the registry as the local admin, HKEY_CURRENT_USER will be that of the local admin, not the other user. However, you can still
[load the hive of another user](https://superuser.com/questions/46399/tool-to-access-another-users-registry-hkey-current-user).

Comment: I think that usually you don't to load keys of other users on the local machine - they're already there under HKEY_USERS.